# Flutter: everytime query database/shared preferences or store the values in a singleton data class?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a couple of screen. One of the screen get the data from the DB. If I change screen, and back again... It reads it again. And again... I wonder if I should make a singleton class that is holding these data instead query the database/shared preferences everytime...?

Comment: I suggest you read this https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple

Answer (score 0):

Use [Provider Package](https://pub.dev/packages/provider):

```
dependencies:
  provider: ^5.0.0
```

Here is the Example :

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

import 'package:admin/models/config.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

class AdminBloc extends ChangeNotifier {
  bool _isSignedIn = false;
  bool _testing = false;


  AdminBloc() {
    checkSignIn();
  
  }

  
  String get userType => _userType;
  bool get isSignedIn => _isSignedIn;


  void checkSignIn() async {
    final SharedPreferences sp = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    _isSignedIn = sp.getBool('signed in') ?? false;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  
}
```